# PHP UPDATE Database

Tags: php, mysql

Just stuck on this mysql UPDATE code.  I modified functioning INSERT code trying to get it to UPDATE my fields.

Anyone know what is wrong with my code or is my error potentially somewhere else.

Thanks in advance!

```
{


            $_POST['dogs'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dogs']);
            $_POST['cats'] = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cats']);


            mysql_query("   UPDATE animals WHERE id='5' SET (dogs,cats)
                            VALUES(

                                '".$_POST['dogs']."',
                                '".$_POST['cats']."',
                            ) ");

        }
```

Comment: `SET ...` before the `WHERE ....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

repair your code like this

```
$dogs = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['dogs']);
$cats = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cats']);
mysql_query("UPDATE animals 
             SET dogs = '$dogs', cats = '$cats' 
             WHERE id='5'");
```

Comment: Thanks @kefy worked like a charm.  I didn't realize WHERE had to be after.